# Two or more variables at a Flask Route REcorator?

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to get two variables from a URL in a Flask Route like this:

```
@app.route('/api/<api-key>/<the-request>', methods=["GET"])
def apirequest(api-key, the-request):
```

This isn't working on Flask. 
How can I have two variables be passed via GET in a URL to Flask?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, however minus (-) sign is not allowed in python var name.

```py
In [4]: test-test=1
  File "<ipython-input-4-5380208e5eef>", line 1
    test-test=1
               ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to operator


In [5]: test_test=1
```